# Close Chrome extension with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to close a chrome extension on-click of a button. The window is the only window open for this app. I thought the below would work but receiving the following console errors.

I am referencing jQuery in my HTML. All I want it to click a button and close my chrome app.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#close").click(function() {
    chrome.app.window.current().close();
  });
});
```

The duplicate in no way explains my issue

Comment: Is it a Chrome application or a Chrome extension ? Your title and content don't tell the same thing.

Comment: Chrome extension Jeff, the above aint a duplicate

Comment: Is it a popup window?

Comment: Yeah, button in the taskbar opens it up, simple html with a button that I want to close it with

Comment: @LukeToss window.close() should do the trick. chrome.app.window is only I believe available in the background scripts.

Comment: Did indeed Adrian, many thanks for you time!

Comment: Everyone is asking if it's an app or an extension because you are using [`chrome.app.`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window), which is only available to **apps, not extensions**. The fact that you are using it means you are making an app, or you are trying to use an API which is not available to extensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this from the window:

```
window.close();
```

Comment: I feel bad it was this simple!!! I was sure I had to user the chome.window - Many thanks :)